# Pandas Get List of Unique Values in Column A for each Unique Value in Column B

Tags: python, pandas, list, sorting, dataframe

I'm finding this problem easy to write out, but difficult to apply with my Pandas Dataframe. 
When searching for anything 'unique values' and 'list' I only get answers for getting the unique values in a list.

There is a brute force solution with a double for loop, but there must be a faster Pandas solution than n^2.

I have a DataFrame with two columns: Name and Likes Food.

As output, I want a list of unique Likes Food values *for each* unique Name.

Example Dataframe df

```
Index        Name       Likes Food

0            Tim        Pizza
1            Marie      Pizza
2            Tim        Pasta
3            Tim        Pizza
4            John       Pizza
5            Amy        Pizza
6            Amy        Sweet Potatoes
7            Marie      Sushi
8            Tim        Sushi
```

I know how to aggregate and groupby the unique count of Likes Food:

```
df.groupby( by='Name', as_index=False ).agg( {'Likes Food': pandas.Series.nunique} )
df.sort_values(by='Likes Food', ascending=False)
df.reset_index( drop=True )
>>>
Index        Name       Likes Food

0            Tim        3
1            Marie      2
2            Amy        2
3            John       1
```

But given that, what ARE the foods for each Name in that DataFrame? For readability, expressed as a list makes good sense. List sorting doesn't matter (and is easy to fix probably).

Example Output

```
<code here>
>>>
Index        Name       Likes Food    Food List

0            Tim        3             [Pizza, Pasta, Sushi]
1            Marie      2             [Pizza, Sushi]
2            Amy        2             [Pizza, Sweet Potatoes]
3            John       1             [Pizza]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain the output without the counts, just try [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html)

```
df.groupby("Name")["Likes"].unique()
Name
Amy             [Pizza, Sweet Potatoes]
John                            [Pizza]
Marie                    [Pizza, Sushi]
Tim               [Pizza, Pasta, Sushi]
Name: Likes, dtype: object
```

additionally, you can used [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)

```
df.groupby("Name").agg(**{"Likes Food": pd.NamedAgg(column='Likes', aggfunc="size"),
                          "Food List": pd.NamedAgg(column='Likes', aggfunc="nunique")}).reset_index()
    Name  Likes Food              Food List
0    Amy           2         [Pizza, Sweet Potatoes]
1   John           1                         [Pizza]
2  Marie           2                  [Pizza, Sushi]
3    Tim           3           [Pizza, Pasta, Sushi]
```

Comment: also if pandas `.25`+, you can try `df.groupby('Name',sort=False).agg(Likes_Food=('Likes','nunique'),Food_List=('Likes','unique'))`

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 you should use `nunique` instead of `size`, if understand OPs question

Comment: This worked great. Thanks! Going to take me a long time to learn this syntax...

Answer (score 1):

To get both columns, also sorted, try this:

```
df = df.groupby("Name")["Likes_Food"].aggregate({'counts': 'nunique',
                                            'food_list': 'unique'}).reset_index().sort_values(by='counts', ascending=False)
df
   Name  counts               food_list
3    Tim       3   [Pizza, Pasta, Sushi]
0    Amy       2  [Pizza, SweetPotatoes]
2  Marie       2          [Pizza, Sushi]
1   John       1                 [Pizza]
```